# Running app from android studio does not save onto my android device anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have only just started android programming, but I have a few basics programs working. Normally when I click run in Android Studio and choose my galaxy nexus as a running device, the app I'm running opens and is saved onto my device, so that I can open my program when I am not plugged into my computer.

However, now when I hit run, my program opens, but it is not saved onto my device.

This happened almost immediately after I changed my application label in my manifest file, but I'm not sure if that's related. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you also change the package name?

Comment: In your device Check your settings in developer options. if you have unchecked "Dont keep activities " option.. just a wild guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that "deploy the APK" is selected in Run-> Edit Configurations

Comment: I do have the "Deploy default APK" option selected under Run/Debug Configurations.

Comment: If you do not have that option then how come this answer is marked as accepted? just wondering ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it at the new project screen. Its greyed out but theres a link  next to it. Just click it. Its next to the Package name and that is the only .app extension you need to execute the apk.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me the problem was that the icon was not appearing on the screen but I found the app was actually stored on the device. I have installed NovaLauncher on a Meizu U20. I went to see the "Applications List"  (tr. it. "Menu delle app"), I found my app icon there and I drag/dropped it on the screen.