# When running my android studio app on my phone, it runs but does not save it on my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-runtime

I have previously ran projects and they not only run but save as apps that I can open again later. Now for some reason this particular projects runs and opens but does not save as an app on my phone.

I'm sure I must be missing some simple setting but I can't find any solutions, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

edit: I am using a Samsung s10 5g, I am coding in Kotlin, I didn't think these things were relevant because I can run my other projects which were also coded in Kotlin and those will save as normal apps on my phone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".Pythagorean">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: which device are you using ?

Comment: In addition to device, what kind of app are you building? dart + flutter? Kotlin?

Comment: Samsung s10 5g, it does work with other projects, and I am using Kotlin. Sorry for not including that information but I didn't think it relevant because I can run other projects and those will both run and save.

Comment: might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634507/running-app-from-android-studio-does-not-save-onto-my-android-device-anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634507/running-app-from-android-studio-does-not-save-onto-my-android-device-anymore)

Comment: My brother with all respect I've stared at that page for hours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running app from android studio does not save onto my android device anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634507/running-app-from-android-studio-does-not-save-onto-my-android-device-anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> apps -> (find the application by name) -> uninstall for all users (Depends upon the device you are using)

Then run your app again via Android Studio in your phone. Check if it helps.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".Pythagorean">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help

Comment: Is your application listed under 'apps' menu in phone?

Comment: yes it is listed, I am not able to launch it from the apps menu though.

Comment: I have added it to the original post